# Create Tooltip in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have retrieved a public API call code for my site and I would like to insert a Tooltip in it to display the Title/description of the image. I would like the title/description of the image to appear above the image no matter on mouse over as in this example of the TOP way:

I watched tutorials, videos, etc. but I can't  Could you help me please?

```php
<?php
  $url = 'https://api.habboemotion.com/public/badges/new';
  $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
  $data = $result->data;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Latest Habbo Badges</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #items {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      
        #items .item {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Badges (<?php echo $data->total; ?>)</h2>
    <div id="items">
      <?php 
        foreach($data->badges AS $badge) {
          if(!$badge->exist) {
            $badge->image = 'https://files.habboemotion.com/resources/images/icons/toolbar_06.gif';
          }
      ?>
       <div class="item">
         <img src="<?php echo $badge->image; ?>" title="<?php echo $badge->code; ?> - <?php echo $badge->name; ?>" alt="" />
       </div> 
      <?php 
        }
      ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried several tutorials but I only got errors in my code...

Comment: I would check out [mcve] as the compiled CSS/HTML is the important part. Also, I don't see any CSS for a tooltip. Unless you are talking about the browser's default tooltip and you want to control it. If so, you will want to use something like javascript. And you can always find small plugins that have that created for you that would probably be easier for you

Comment: _"I tried several tutorials but I only got errors in my code..."_ - leaving it at just stating that, isn't going to help. If you are getting error messages - then try to understand _what_ they are trying to tell you, and go research their core phrasing for further explanations if this is giving you trouble.